# Set Background as null

Tags: android

If I use the following line in the xml layout:

```
android:background="@null"
```

1. Is it safe?
2. Is effective from a performance point of view? Or
       it's better to set the layout's or the component's bacground from the
       actual code as null?

Comment: Why do you want to set `android:background="@null"`? If you don't want to apply background then no need to add this property, i think so.

Comment: I was watching a Google I/O tutorial and I heard that the UI will be much more efficient if you remove the background.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. `android:background="@null"` is absolutely safe. If you want to set the background based on your logic in code, you can definitely use this; and if you do not set the background in code, it is still the same and will never cause any problems.
2. From a performance point of view, you should load the background via XML instead of programmatically because your layout will be loaded only once from the XML. If you set it in code based on your logic, it may be loaded more than once. However, in either case, the performance is almost the same, not a big difference. You should decide which approach to use from your logic point of view (if you will never change the background, use the XML approach). The point is, use the image of the appropriate size as the background. That will make the real difference in performance. Big images will take more time to load in either approach.

Answer (score 4):

i think you are looking for this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, because you dont need to find this view on code side, it will effect to performance positive.  and i dont think that it is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

If background is not needed then there is no need to mention it in xml. At least it will be one less parsing of XML element.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used for a number of things. I specifically use it to remove that underline in my EditText's. It is safe to use but just be sure that you require it in your code.

Comment: Hey @Aayush, what do you mean by "require it in your code"?

Comment: By require I mean if you really need to use it in your code for some other purpose or functionality.